# axios retry with timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, axios-retry

I have a use case where i need to retry Axios POST requests in case of API timeout while trying to POST the request. I need to retry 3 times in case of API timeout and each retry request should timeout in 4 secs if the POST operation cant be completed in that period. I am using the below code but neither the retry or the timeout seems to work. Could you let me know what is wrong and the correct code snippet for this?

```
axiosRetry(axios, { retries: 3 });
axios.post(url,payload,{headers:header},{timeout:4000})
```

Comment: POST requires enabling specifically. By default only idempotent calls are retried (i.e. GETs)

Comment: @Dean  do  you have a link to this documentation?  I've been looking for this answer for a while.

Answer (score 4):

[retry-axios](https://github.com/JustinBeckwith/retry-axios) has its own named configuration, and the retry delay can be setup at top level i.e.

```
const res = await axios({
  url,
  method: 'post',
  data: payload,
  raxConfig: {
    retry: 3,
    retryDelay: 4000
  }
});
```

Comment: Note that the original question was on axios-retry, not retry-axios. Those are different libraries.